# Password Check Program - checking capitals, lowercase letters, digit and special character

Tags: java, passwords, verify

I have an assignment that requires me to create a password checking program.

The password must be at least 8 characters, contain both capital and lower case letters, a digit and a special character.

I believe I am close to solving this problem but my skills are still developing and I've hit a wall.

```
package project1;

/**
 *
 * @author danechristian
 */
import java.util.*;
public class Project1 
{
    static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    static final String SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = "!,#,$,%,^,&,*,|";
    static String password;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        System.out.println("Create a password: ");
        password = console.next();

        if (validPassword(password))
        {
            System.out.println("Password Saved");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid Passowrd. Password "
                    + "must contain atleast 1 capital letter"
                    + "1 lower case letter, 1 digit, 1"
                    + "special character (!#$%^&*|) and "
                    + "be atleast 8 characters long");
        }
    }

public static boolean validPassword(String password)
    {
        boolean upCase = false;
        boolean loCase = false;
        boolean isDigit = false;
        boolean spChar = false;

        if (password.length() >= 8)
           {
            for (int i = 0; i < password.length() - 1; i++)
               {
                if (Character.isUpperCase(password.charAt(i)))
                {
                    upCase = true;
                }

                if (Character.isLowerCase(password.charAt(i)))
                {
                    loCase = true;
                }

                if (Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i)))
                {
                    isDigit = true;
                }

                if (SPECIAL_CHARACTERS.contains(password))
                {
                    spChar = true;
                }
               } 
           }         
        return (upCase && loCase && isDigit && spChar);
    }   

}
```

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: Can't you just use regex for this?

Comment: I don't know where you hit a wall with this because for me everything is easy and obvious. Therefore, I'm unable to see your problem. Please explain where it is.

Comment: doesn't evaluate cap letter lower case letters digits or special characters. not familiar with regex.

Comment: It's bad practice to store a password in a String. Should use a char[] for starters. Strings are immutable which means that the password will sit in RAM when you are finished with it.

Answer (score 3):

In order to check have something like this:

```
public static boolean validPassword(String password){
        boolean upCase = false;
        boolean loCase = false;
        boolean isDigit = false;
        boolean spChar = false;
     if (password.length()>7){
          if (password.matches(".+[A-Z].+")){
              upCase = true;
          }
          if (password.matches(".+[a-z].+")){
              loCase = true;
          }
          if (password.matches(".+[1-9].+")){
              isDigit = true;
          }
          if (SPECIAL_CHARACTERS.contains(password)){
               spChar = true;
          }
     }
  return (upCase && loCase && isDigit && spChar);
}
```

Comment: but doesn't this mean that e.g. the digit is not first or last?

Comment: @ropo The greedy symbol + represents 0 or more times so it does check the first and last character. Link to java regex https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: elegant answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

**solved by changing**

if (SPECIAL_CHARACTERS.contains(password)){
               spChar = true;

**to**

if (SPECIAL_CHARACTERS.contains(password.substring(i,i+1))){
                    spChar = true;

this checks for the string within the string.

also, I removed the "- 1" from my for statement so that the bounds were corrects. also removed the commas from the SPECIAL_CHARACTERS constant.

the program now runs without issue, thanks for the advice everyone.